# skip visible items from animating using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm using waypoints to have fadeIn animation when the user scrolled down, and it worked. But as you can see, during the onload, there's a fadeIn too for the first few visible items.

How to not to have that? since I binded all .card to way[point.

My js

```
$(function() {

var waypoints = $('.card').waypoint(function (direction) {
                        $(this).addClass("animated fadeIn");


            }, {
                offset: '90%'
            });

});
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/ghx49d7x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if its exactly what you want, but you can add a variable to indicate if the page has loaded or not and only add `fadeIn` if it has:

```
$(function () {
    var pageLoaded = false;
    var waypoints = $('.card').waypoint(function (direction) {
        $(this).addClass("animated"
            + (pageLoaded ? " fadeIn" : ""));
    }, {
        offset: '90%'
    });
    pageLoaded = true;
});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghx49d7x/3/

Comment: thanks so much! but can you take a look on this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722787/lazy-loading-using-animation-delay